# Synonymize [openjdk-21] to [java-21]

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

Since Java 21 has been released in September, questions tagged with [java-21](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-21) have been asked.
Similarly, some questions also use the tag [openjdk-21](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openjdk-21).
However, most of them are not specifically about OpenJDK but general questions about Java 21.

I therefore propose to make [openjdk-21](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openjdk-21) a synonym of [java-21](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-21) similar to [openjdk-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openjdk-8), [openjdk-11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openjdk-11) and [openjdk-17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openjdk-17). It might also be a good idea to consider [openjdk-12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openjdk-12) since that has essentially the same issue just no one seem to have cared about it yet.

Comment: Why not just remove the openjdk-21 tag and replace all its uses with java-21? Same for the openjdk-12 tag.

Comment: The synonym is a more permanent solution, but there aren't really that many questions to speak of here so you might as well fix the tags. Probably in the past for like openjdk-8 the questions were in the thousands.

Comment: For [openjdk-12], I think removing makes sense since it isn't likely to be recreated. With [openjdk-21], it would probably be recreated pretty fast.

Comment: You have to consider what's in front of you. Retagging is something that can be done right now. The request for a synonym has been open for 5 days and it's got one upvote; Literally nobody cares about a tag which has a dozen questions.

Comment: Yes but the tag would be recreated quickly and there is a requirement on authoritative knowledge/another trusted user agreeing or whatever it was called even for removing small tags.